# How to get certificate value using ndk in java

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, certificate

I want to get the key value of the certificate as jni.

The code is shown below.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_abc_app_database_policy_SSLSocketFactory_getKeyString(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n\
                              MIIGdjCCBV6gAQWBAgIQYNp/7quITLkJD6xSbO+wBDANBgkLRkiG9w0BAQsFADCB\n\
                              kDELMAkGA1UEBGECR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIEWWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G\n\

...
...
                               -----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");
```

When I tried it like this

I saw these errors.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: error: 0906D066: PEM routines:
>   PEM_read_bio: bad end line

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `"` to replace `\n\`：

just try：

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
                   "MIIGdjCCBV6gAQWBAgIQYNp/7quITLkJD6xSbO+wBDANBgkLRkiG9w0BAQsFADCB"
                   "kDELMAkGA1UEBGECR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIEWWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G"


-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `\n` each line.

See official RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468 about textual encoding for certificates.